# I have found that academia is not for me. Expected last year of my Ph.D soon. Any advice on transitioning out?

Tags: publications, phd, advisor, cv, industry

I am an upcoming fourth year Ph.D student in Applied Experimental Psychology with an accepted MA in Experimental Psychology who has realized that academia is just not for me. The notion that all of my work can be discarded in an instant and negatively affect my program progress is what bothered me in particular. The notion that research could also be developed and completed, only for publications to possibly never accept it, also bothers me. I've also had awful advising at both the MA and early on in my Ph.D program as well. Although my new advisor is excellent, I have seen so much of what can go wrong in academia that I can only find the energy to work on my dissertation and whatever other work will come from my upcoming fellowship.

As of now, I can only find the energy to work on my dissertation as my only research project, looking for post Ph.D jobs, working on an online UX certificate, and prepping for my full-time instructor teaching load for next academic year. This leads me to why I am posting and why I mentioned all of the prior points. What I can start to do in order to plan for transitioning to non-academic jobs with my Ph.D? My main sellable skills are the usual basic data analysis (correlations and regressions mainly), reading and editing Python code, experiment building and creation (Experiment Builder, E-Prime), and grant writing (I obtained a $35,000 fellowship for my final academic year). Those who have seen my previous posts likely saw that I am concerned about my CV and how underdeveloped it is compared to other candidates. I now realize that its my characteristic narrow focus (or "hyperfocus" as its called in some circles) that's partially responsible for my underdeveloped CV. I can still attribute my poor advising in my first four years of graduate school as the other reason for this though.

I will tell my current advisor about my priorities at some point. However, will it still benefit me to work on publications (I have none), different research projects, and other things that are normally academic CV builders? I am not sure what is translatable to industry but I want to work translatable things as much as possible.

Comment: 1) Go to your campus Career Center or whatever it is called.  2) Unfortunately I think industry will be even less accommodating to your neurodivergence as academia.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Ah, so you read my first post then. I am about to contact my Career Center. However, I've had issues with them in the past not understanding what I do since they appear to be undergraduate oriented. I am at an R2 so there's not much support for graduate students in general.

Comment: The best advice will likely come from either professors in your (or related) department(s), and recently graduated PhD students in your field. It seems highly unlikely that all recent graduates remained in academia. Campus career centers don't seem to serve undergraduates very well (which would be a question itself), much less grad students.

Comment: Some Ph.D. topics have many employment opportunities outside academia.  I do not know about "experimental psychology".  But I imagine candidates with a Ph.D. have more possibilities than those without.  Alternate: there are academic positions at non-research colleges and universities.  You would do teaching and (later) administration, not research.

Comment: Research projects are useful in that they are projects. They teach project management and execution. Make sure you are good on those skills and will have good examples to discuss in interviews. Also look at job descriptions for positions you would want. Figure out what required skills you could include on a resume and which you need to add.

Comment: You're asking a community of people who have failed to transition out of academia.  Why would you expect us to have any good answers?

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Some of us did transition out of academia, but hang around here for reasons ranging from "remind myself why I left" to "work in academia-adjacent areas which don't have their own dedicated SE".

Comment: While I don't want to discourage you from transitioning out of academia if you are unhappy, I would want to say that in "the real world" you have even less guarantees of good work leading to praise, glory, and career progression than in academia. School is pretty much the only time in your life where you can be reasonably sure that if you properly do the assignments you will get your reward (aka a good grade). The rest of all of our lives is a lot more chaotic.

Comment: @xLeitix That perspective is super helpful. Edit: It is worth noting that I might also just be burned out and am looking for some fresh work too. I've had issues with employment for most of my life. I also had academic issues early in my undergrad that tanked my overall GPA to a 3.3 (major was 3.5 though). Master's I also did (3.48 GPA), but this was related to dental issues I had to explain. Final classes in my Ph.D pre quals were all As and A-'s though. I got into a Ph.D program since I had relevant lab experience and my program didn't mind graduate GPA if I dodged probation.

Comment: @zzmondo1 It's completely understandable that after your PhD you are looking for something else to do. I would say this is true for the vast majority of people.

Answer (score 4):

In another question, you mentioned:

> my neurodivergent conditions (e.g., autism, ADHD-I, emotion
> dysregulation, etc.)

I'd suggest adding that info to your question here as it's potentially relevant.

Depending on where you are, there may be programs that assist neurodivergent people in finding employment. For instance, [Dandelions](https://dxc.com/au/en/about-us/social-impact-practice/dxc-dandelion-program) is a program that works to place neurodivergent people in IT careers. I'm not recommending (nor anti-recommending) that particular program, but I'd encourage you to check out what programs might be available to you and contact any that appeal. Workplace SE might be an appropriate place to ask about such programs.

As well as industry, consider government work. I don't think there is any area that's perfect for ND people, but some government agencies can be pretty good, and may have disability programs. I work in a R&D area of government; it has its annoyances, but I get to do interesting research without the "publish or perish" pressures of academia, and with better job security.

> I now realize that its my characteristic narrow focus (or "hyperfocus" as its called in some circles) that's partially responsible for my underdeveloped CV. I can still attribute my poor advising in my first four years of graduate school as the other reason for this though.

You can, but I'm not sure that will be helpful. In general, potential employers are more interested in what skills you can/can't demonstrate than in the reasons why. Focussing on how somebody else let you down can often backfire; fairly or unfairly, it'll often be interpreted as making excuses. Every job will have difficult people and obstacles, and employers will usually be looking for people who can resolve those obstacles. This is something that can be tough for us ND people - my own PhD dragged out a couple of years longer than it ought've because other people were holding up something I needed and I hadn't figured out how to deal with that situation.

I would recommend focussing instead on what you can do to fix those gaps. Even the fact that you've identified them as gaps and are taking steps to work on them gives a prospective employer some evidence that you're capable of taking the initiative in working past obstacles.

> will it still benefit me to work on publications (I have none), different research projects, and other things that are normally academic CV builders? I am not sure what is translatable to industry but I want to work translatable things as much as possible.

Different industries will have different priorities. Publications and research projects will be more important for R&D-type jobs than for, say, generic IT. But just about any employer will be glad to see evidence that you have the ability to complete complex projects, especially in the face of adversity.

From my perspective, as somebody who has been in a similar position to you, and then later in my career ended up interviewing candidates from academia, these candidates are often technically strong but weak in team skills, and perhaps narrow in communication skills (good at academic writing, weaker at other aspects of communication).

If you can demonstrate your ability to work with others (e.g. organise a conference or a seminar series) and show ability to communicate outside academic papers, that's likely to be a plus. Successful grant writing is good here as it shows ability to influence others, not just to tell them stuff, and if you can show ability to communicate with non-technical audiences even better. This is particularly important if people know you're autistic, as autistics often get stereotyped as being unable to communicate effectively.

Beyond that, I think most advice would be industry-specific.